# eclipse.ini file and options

Tags: eclipse, ini

I have downloaded eclipse and looked into its eclipse.ini file which contains this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Why does it contain the option:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
```

two times where 'M' is used in the first case and 'm' is used in the second case?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a bug in packaging or a plugin. Please open a bug report at bugs.eclipse.org. Make sure to specify exactly which package you've downloaded and if you installed any plugins (list which ones) after you've extracted the initial package.

Answer (score 0):

I went into many options for the eclipse.ini.

I use Java 7 with a Intel Core i7 with 8Go of Ram, and windows 7. The performance of eclipse and the impact of eclipse.ini depends on the configuration of the machine.
We have big projects with big workspaces.

Here is my eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-vmargs
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:CompileThreshold=500
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:ErrorFile=./hs_err_pid<pid>.log
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=true
-Dawt.nativeDoubleBuffering=true
-Duser.language=en_US
-Xverify:none
-XgcPrio:deterministic
-XpauseTarget:20
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0
-XX:SurvivorRatio=128
```

I wish good luck to you.
If you have time to test it and have any comment, please help us improve it.

Regards
ECI